# Minimum margin from side for jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

By default dialog is centered like so:

```
$(el).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

Is there any way to set "minimum" distance from side? (e.g. top position should be not less than 50px). And is there any event that fires when dialog position is changed? Can't find it...

Thank you.

Comment: $(el).dialog('option', 'position', 'center').css('margin-top','50px');   but not sure if this solves yourt issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up fighting with this `position` option and just did this:

```
$(el).dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
var dWindow = $(el).closest('.ui-dialog');
if( parseInt( dWindow.css('top'), 10) < 50 )  {
    dWindow.css('top', '50px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [jQuery UI position utility](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) ?
It saids:

> Each dimension can also contain offsets, in pixels or percent, e.g., "right+10 top-25%". Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.

Comment: Thx, I've seen it, the problem is that I need dialog to be centered (size of it is dynamic) but have minimum margin from top